# JQueryUI Dialog ways of insert text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm using JQueryUI dialog to show modal confirmation, it works fine, the problem is the text I want to show to the user. I don't wanna use title atributte for this purpose, so I need to put the text inside the html tag div (dialog). The only issue about this method, is that the text put inside the div or p, or span, etc, it shows before the dialog is opened, so I have an extra effort to hide the text via css, and show when dialog opens.
Is that the only way to do with dialog jqueryui?

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to hide content. I think you are not using `autoOpen` attribute of jquery dialog. Jquery ui dialog hides the content if you use `autoOpen:true`.

```
<div id="dialog_content">
  <p>Here goes your dialog content</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder='sample text'>
</div>

<button id="click_me">
Click Me
</button>
```

and the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dialog_content').dialog({
        autoOpen:false
  });
  $('#click_me').click(function(){
    $('#dialog_content').dialog('open');
  });
});
```

Check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/r5uhag3w/3/)

If this is not what you mean, then please post issue with a code

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="dialog">
<p>
 This is a text dialog
</p>
</div>

$('#dialog').dialog({
autoOpen: false                        
});
```

Even with autoOpen is set to false, it displays the text "This is a text dialog" inside the

. I have to hide with CSS, but I think this is a issue I should be avoiding by using the JQueryUI dialog.